# Segmentation fault using strcat(str1,str[pos])

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* str="abcdef";
    char* str1 = malloc(strlen(str)+1);

    strcat(str1,str[1]);
    printf("String = %s\n", str1);

    return(0);
}
```

So i get the "Segmentation fault" when i want to to concatenate a letter from str to str1 `strcat(str1,str[1])`

Comment: You are passing a character where a pointer to a string is expected. This usually ends up in a segfault.

Comment: Your compiler should have given you an error (or at least warning) message on the call to `strcat`. If so, you have (a) ignored the compiler's diagnostic and (b) not mentioned it in your question.

Comment: `char* str1 = (char *)malloc(strlen(str) * sizeof(char));`
 ?

Comment: @Hearner no, `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition and it needs the `+1` for the string terminator. And, it does not need the cast. That line in the question at least, was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way if you want to append the second character of `str` to `str1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str="abcdef";
    char *str1 = malloc(strlen(str)+1); // malloc just allocates the memory

    strcpy(str1, str); // you need to copy str to str1
    printf("String = %s\n", str1);

    char str2[] = { str[1], '\0' };

    strcat(str1, str2); // strcat takes two null terminated strings as arguments
    printf("String = %s\n", str1);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str1` is malloc()'d, but uninitialized. That means that memory chunk contains whatever random garbage was in that memory when your program started up. Since `strcat` appends to the end of its destination, it'll search `*str1` for a null, and then start scribbling there.

Since you didn't initialize str1, that null could be ANYWHERE farther ahead in ram, and you're likely scribbling on something important, like the stack.

You need to memset() that memory chunk to all null, or at least set str[1] to be null.

Comment: your'e also missing a point.OP is passing str[1] to strcat,which is a character...

Comment: The first serious bug I saw was this one.  Why bother looking any further than 'strcat(str1'...?  That's a serious bug, right there, so I don't really understand the downvote on this:(

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't DV but originally commented that *set `str[1]` to be null* is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strcat` appends one nul-terminated string onto another. You have allocated memory for the new string, but it isn't yet a "string" until it is nul-terminated, do this with

```
*str1 = 0;
```

or alternatively with

```
str1[0] = 0;
```

Then when you append the original string with `strcat` you are passing a single `char` with

```
strcat(str1, str[1]);
```

and this needs to be

```
strcat(str1, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcat()` depends on the null terminating character.It searches the first argument that is supplied to it,which must be a null-terminated string,and then concatenates to it the second argument,which also must be a null-terminated string.

When you allocate memory with `malloc()`,the resulting allocation is uninitialized.So,calling `strcat()` with it invokes undefined behavior.One possible solution is to set the first element of the allocated memory to the null terminating character `'\0'`.You can also use `calloc()` function which initialize the entire allocation to 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* str = "abcdef";
    char* str1 = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    str1[0] = '\0';

    strcat(str1, str);
    printf("String = %s\n", str1);

    return(0);
}
```